# Openstm32 sprintf crash

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, stm32f4

I use a STM32F407 with Openstm32 (GCC compiler). The Program seems to crash, if I use sprintf("...%d",integer) (Debugger stops directly at sprintf), but seems to work fine if I use sprintf("string"). Someone any idea what could be wrong?

```
int main(void)
{
  TM_MPU6050_t MPU6050_Data;
  char str[120];
  /* Initialize system */
  SystemInit();



  /* Initialize USART, PB6, PB7*/
  TM_USART_Init(USART1, TM_USART_PinsPack_2, 57600);

  /* Initialize MPU6050 sensor SCL: PA8, SDA: PC9 */
  if (TM_MPU6050_Init(&MPU6050_Data, TM_MPU6050_Device_0, TM_MPU6050_Accelerometer_2G, TM_MPU6050_Gyroscope_2000s) != TM_MPU6050_Result_Ok) {
    /* Display error to user */
    TM_USART_Puts(USART1, "MPU6050 Error\n");

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1);
  }

  while (1) {
    sprintf(str,"Test");
    TM_USART_Puts(USART1, str);
    for(int i=0;i<8000000;i++); //delay

    TM_MPU6050_ReadAll(&MPU6050_Data);
    int i=MPU6050_Data.Accelerometer_X;
    sprintf(str, "Acceleration X: %d",5); //Crash

    TM_USART_Puts(USART1, str);

    for(int i=0;i<8000000;i++); //delay
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the matter with `snprintf` ?

Comment: The libraries provided with embedded development tools usually include stripped-down versions of the printf-related functions to give the developer the option to reduce the amount of memory used for the printf-related functions.  The IDE usually provides a project option to select which version of printf is linked.  Which version of printf does your project use?  Also, is the stack big enough for sprintf or are you experiencing a stack overflow?

Answer (score -1):

## Maybe you erased the memory of `sprintf` somewhere

### Like below:

```c
    char message[32] = {0};
    
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    sprintf(message, "Hello: %s\n", "World"); // Will not cash
    
    FLASH_Erase_Sector(FLASH_SECTOR_1, VOLTAGE_RANGE_1);
    sprintf(message, "Hello: World\n"); // Also worked by compiler-optimization 
    sprintf(message, "Hello: %s\n", "World"); // Crashed here !!!
```